# How old should a seed-grown Passiflora ligularis be to set fruit?

Tags: indoors, shrubs, fruits, vines

I have five [granadilla (Passiflora ligularis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora_ligularis) grown from seed this year. How long does it take for them to bloom and bear fruit, assuming they receive proper light and watering?

Comment: Difficult to find much about how long it takes to flower and fruit, but there's a thread here http://www.cloudforest.com/cafe/forum/34350.html posted by someone who says it took 3 years before the first fruits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your cultivar and your climate. In this [article](http://www.tropicalpermaculture.com/growing-passionfruit.html) they say (quote:)

> **How long does passionfruit take to fruit?**
>
> That depends on several factors. The tropical varieties fruit quicker
>   then the purple passionfruit.
>
> Any passionfruit will reach maturity sooner if growing in a warmer
>   climate.
>
> A passionfruit vine planted in spring fruits sooner than a
>   passionfruit planted in autumn.
>
> In ideal conditions (early spring planting in the tropics) you can get
>   fruit within six months. Autumn planting in a cooler climate means you
>   may have to wait for over 12 months.

According to the article I refer to, the plant (vine) is a fast grower, so ideally when you plant them next spring you'll have fruit within 6 months. That is theory of course. Probably your plant has to be large enough first, which may take a year (or more).